# Material won't show in solid mode

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I made a football field material by watching a tutorial and have it on the object but I can't get it to become visible on the plane in solid mode. It is only visible in material preview mode. Heres a screenshot of it in solid mode and the material. It's not just a color but also has white lines and darker strips.
[image: Image of the object in blender in solid mode]

Comment: By default you won't see any material in Solid mode, it's a mode that is supposed to be as light as possible so that you can model quickly, that said you can display a texture: Open the Viewport Shading panel and click on Texture instead of Material

Comment: I clicked on texture there but it didn't make any difference, It's still as it was I guess.

Comment: I meant image texture, do you use an image texture? If not you won't see anything, again Solid mode is not made to show any material, instead switch to Material preview or Rendered preview mode

Comment: Yes but when I export this object as an fbx to use in unity I get it without that material/texture that I have added onto it which is only visible in material preview.

Comment: please share your object or at least a part of it, or at least show a screenshot of your Shader Editor, it looks like Unity can't read the material, it seems to be your problem here, no?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aDdW0C-dQPtkdY9n3t3Kn3auVRPji0DE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You haven't packed your image, but there's a shader missing between your Image Texture and your Mix Shader, try to put a Diffuse shader for example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. Procedural materials never show up in solid mode, and image textures will only show up if you set them to be visible on that object in the Viewport Display panel of the Object Properties.

Comment: I still don't get it, I am actually trying to export this object to unity to use as a football field but when I export it as a fbx and place it there, there isn't anyting on it, just a grey object like it's showing in the solid view now, I want to export it so that the field material comes with it.

Comment: @SaifAli You didn’t mention that. Most export formats do not support procedural materials. You’ll have to bake it to an image texture. There are multiple answered questions on this site and resources elsewhere about that.